# Why is not there any \refcounter command in LaTeX?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

We have the `\stepcounter` command in LaTeX where
`\stepcounter{counter}` adds one to the counter and resets all
subsidiary counters.

We also have the `\refstepcounter` command where
`\refstepcounter{counter}` works like `\stepcounter`, except it also
defines the current `\ref` value to be the result of `\thecounter`.

Now, sometimes, specially when building some home grown macro, we face
a situation (believe me, I have been in that situation more than once
in my life) where we need to `\ref` to a custom counter without
actually incrementing the value.

If we check the definition of 
`\refstepcounter`,  we see something like this:

```
\stepcounter {#1}\protected@edef \@currentlabel {\csname p@#1\endcsname \cs
name the#1\endcsname}
```

So, defining the command `\refcounter` would mean a simple
deletion of the first incrementing part, namely, 
removing `\stepcounter {#1}`.

Why is not the `\refcounter` command part of base LaTeX?

Is the reason a plain and simple omission or there
is a specific reason behind this?

Comment: If hyperref is loaded the definition is different.

Comment: it is so rarely needed, and you can always do `\addtocounter{foo}{-1}\refstepcounter{foo}` if you need it and don't want to look at the internals.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With what effects?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I always did something like that over these years (from the early 90's). My question is a *why* and not  a *how*. The how part is simple. And the why part is out of simple curiosity.

Comment: @Masroor "Why" questions are not really answerable. Just that no one who has maintained latex ever thought of any reason to implement such a command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but not together with hyperref, you would get a " destination with the same identifier (name{section.1})" warning.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer hmm probably you would, true.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not "probably", I tried ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, now I get it, at least partially.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you would if the counter had already beem refetepcountered so the hyperref label already set but if the counter had not been used as a label and just previously set with `\setcounter` then it should work shouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, the problem are two \refstepcounters to the same value.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, even the how part is exactly not that simple when you consider the hyperref scenario.

Comment: @Masroor the problem is that your description what the command should do is unclear. E.g. has \refcounter{section}\label{blub}\pageref{blub} actually some sense?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, it would not. But, sometimes, when have some custom counter used to be referenced without incrementing the value at some random point, we need that command. When I was more active writing macros about a decade ago, I needed that a couple of times. Yesterday, that scenario came to my mind at some idle moment and thought of this forum to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: `hyperref` will check for `\theH<counter>` for the hyperlink name. (If not defined, it will just use `\the<counter>`.) So it's possible to have a counter that's used as a prefix in `\theH...` that's automatically incremented. For example, `\newcounter{prefix} \renewcommand{\theHsection}{\theprefix.\thesection}` and later `\stepcounter{prefix}\addtocounter{section}{-1}\refstepcounter{section}`. That will avoid the duplicate identifier problem.